# Flutter: Authenticate using Play Games in Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies, google-play-games

I have Facebook and Google authentication working fine:

[image]

Recently I added also Play Games (this is configured and working fine in my app) but I can't find how to sign in using this. Some articles have [Google's code to singing](https://nagachiang.github.io/flutter-google-play-games-sign-in-with-firebase/#) and the only reference I found is this, but not Flutter related:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/play-games

There is also this package, but it's not really used:
https://pub.dev/packages/game_services_firebase_auth

Is that package the only way?